# When does the device go to sleep?

Tags: android, multithreading

I saw a great speech from Commonsware's Mark about multithreading and using wakeful services yesterday at AppsWorld London. He recommends using [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) or [WakeFulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) in some situations to ensure your app will be able to continue some long processing and prevent the device to go to sleep.

I have an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gpo.greenpower) that does some background processing regularly when the device screen is off. I use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to have it get the stuff done regularly.
Since I have a large user base (200.000 active users), I get to see all kind of weird cases when users send me some logfile. Among others I could see that on some devices after the alarm will be triggered, the app starts doing his job and then suddenly just doesn't do anything for many seconds, or even minutes (no entry in the logfile for a while). I assume this is because the phone goes to sleep.
What bugs me is that this happens only on some devices, for instance it would happen a lot on Samsung SGS2+, but not on SGS2, SGS3 or SGS4.

So what I'm wondering is: what is the policy to decide when to put the phone to sleep? Is it Android deciding or is it lower at the Linux level?
How much tweaking from the manufacturer is allowed? Shouldn't the sleep policy be part of the [Android Compatibility](http://source.android.com/compatibility/) definition?
Extra question: Are there some levels of being asleep, like several levels of CPU speed, or is it just boolean sleeping / not sleeping?

Comment: It's Mark, not Mike :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the policy to decide when to put the phone to sleep?

Generally speaking, if nothing is holding a `WakeLock`, the device is free to go into "opportunistic suspend" mode, where the CPU stops executing instructions.

> Is it Android deciding or is it lower at the Linux level?

The Linux kernel -- via Android extensions originally, now rolled into the stock kernel -- handles opportunistic suspend. Userland apps, like SDK apps, can use `WakeLock` to block opportunistic suspend..

In terms of how the kernel is configured in terms of opportunistic suspend, I have no idea.

> Shouldn't the sleep policy be part of the Android Compatibility definition?

Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

> Are there some levels of being asleep, like several levels of CPU speed, or is it just boolean sleeping / not sleeping?

From the standpoint of an Android SDK app, and with respect to the CPU, right now, it is "boolean sleeping/not sleeping", as compared to Intel SpeedStep-style CPU frequency changes. Certain multi-core CPUs may turn on and off cores to save power, but this is generally independent from opportunistic suspend.